# Reputation Calculations

Tags: support, reputation-history, achievements-dialog

Yesterday when checking my reputation in the toolbar, I noticed a **-10** as a result of a user being removed.

[image]

I then checked the reputation tab in my profile which showed a different total, and included an additional **-10** (for user removed) and a further **-10** as result of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630585/duplicate-input-input-holding-incorrect-value-generated-in-html/40688742#40688742) I had answered being removed by Community

[image]

Is this a bug, or am I just not understanding how the results are displayed?

Comment: What is the question here?  On the margin there appears to be a timing issue between when a user/question was removed?  Do you think the accounting is wrong?  Are you wondering about the timing of scoring?

Comment: @StephenRauch, No - the question is about why I see different results (the total, and the different 'removed' votes) between the reputation tab and the repuation shown in the toolbar. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Deleted posts are not listed in the achievements drop down (it takes the “vote never took place” view on deletions). I bet that one of those “deleted user” votes was on the deleted post as well. So in the end only one vote remeained on a non-deleted post, which is why you see the -10 User Removed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I assume that a user was deleted. They had voted on that answer and another one, so 2 x 'user removed' is for the same user, plus another -10 for the other vote because the question was deleted. If its correct that it takes a _vote never took place_ approach that probably explains it (although I am curious why its calculated differently in the achievements drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The achievement box does not include votes for *deleted posts*.

Two of the events in your reputation tab are related to deleted posts (here, the same deleted post). The [deleted *Duplicate input / input ...* post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630585/duplicate-input-input-holding-incorrect-value-generated-in-html/40688742#40688742) had two upvotes, one from the deleted user, and one from someone else, so you first lost the vote from the deleted user, then the remaining vote when the post was deleted.

There are basically two logs being kept that affect your reputation:

- The change log, a list of events that influence your reputation. This gives you a timeline of your score, as it changes. If a user or post is deleted, you lose votes, but the change log will retain both the original up- and downvote events on the post, as well as the 'user removed' and 'post removed' events that record how much your reputation changed because of the removal. This log is used in your reputation tab; you get to see both the original votes that were later invalidated, and the deletions that invalidated them.
- The vote log; the list of active, timestamped votes that make up your total reputation. Votes have an integer value, positive or negative or zero; vote values can be adjusted from the usual +5, +10, -1 and -2 values to adjust for the daily reputation cap, and the minimum reputation limit.

  The `/reputation` audit shows this view. Votes on posts that have been deleted, or votes from deleted users, are not part of this log, as those votes are no longer active. Your total reputation is the result of summing the values in this vote log.

  Some events in the change log above trigger a [recalculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126922/what-does-se-use-to-calculate-reputations-sql-aggregate-functions-a-manual-met) of the logs, to account for the reputation cap. Votes are dropped from the vote log, others have their value adjusted.

Between these two logs, it can sometimes be confusing to work out how your reputation changed; you can end up with days on your reputation tab that give you more or fewer points for a given day than could otherwise be expected given the reputation cap or the minimum reputation limit. On balance the tally is always accurate, as later events in the changelog will show the loss or gain of reputation discrepancy in the form of 'removed' events.

The achievements box is special in that it prefers showing you the *positive* changes from the change log. For example, the number on the box in the bar only shows positive deltas since you last looked (so downvotes and vote invalidations are 'delayed' until you have a positive delta again). In the same vein deleted posts are not shown; even the original upvotes on such a post are removed. Like the reputation tab, the tally is still accurate, but the number of entries shown in the box is limited so it is not always clear that it is.

So in the end, your achievement box shows you the correct numbers, given that it doesn't show you the original votes for the now-deleted post *either*. Arguably, it shouldn't show you the 'user removed' event either (opting instead for not showing the original upvote).

Do note that the reputation tab doesn't show deleted posts either, not by default. You need to tick the *show removed posts* checkbox at the bottom to see events for removed posts. I suspect that if you unchecked that box, you'd only see one *-10 User was removed* event there too.